# Google App Engine deployment: missing file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have a problem with google app engine. It used to work but now I can't figure out whats wrong...

```
python: can't open file 'google_appengine/dev_appserver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: How does this error occur? Which command did you issue? Which code segment causes this error? What did you try to solve this problem? Please give further details!

Comment: The dev appserver is used in development, not deployment, surely.

Answer (score 1):

apologize for the delay in getting back to this.

1) it happens when command is executed outside google_appengine directory e.g.

```
abid@abid-webdev:~/Documents/GAE_projects/helloworld$ python google_appengine/dev_appserver.py helloworld/
```

> python: can't open file 'google_appengine/dev_appserver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

2) now when i run from the directory where i have

"google_appengine folder" and project, it works grand :)

abid@abid-webdev:~/Documents/GAE_projects$ ls

`google_appengine`  `helloworld`

```
abid@abid-webdev:~/Documents/GAE_projects$ python google_appengine/dev_appserver.py helloworld/
```

> Allow dev_appserver to check for updates on startup? (Y/n): y
>   dev_appserver will check for updates on startup.  To change this setting, edit /home/abid/.appcfg_nag

3) another thing i noticed, google docs says->[https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld][1] to use ->

```
google_appengine/dev_appserver.py helloworld/ this command -
```

whereas i used

> python google_appengine/dev_appserver.py helloworld/  as suggested on udacity forums->
>
> http://forums.udacity.com/questions/6003945/with-opensuse-121-the-python-app-refuses-to-work

thanks all for your help. cheers